# nested object is undefined using find

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
const value = data.find(t => t.user).name;
```

given above code, my app break if user is null, what's the fallback I could do? I feel this could be duplicated:

```
data.find(t => t.user) && data.find(t => t.user).name;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could `or` the value of the `find` with an empty object.

```js
const data = [{}];
const value = (data.find(t => t.user === 'someUserId') || {}).name;
console.log(value);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use the [Optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). `value` will then equal `undefined` and you won't run into an error:

```js
const data = [{}];
const value = data.find(t => t.user === 'someUserId')?.name;
console.log(value);
```

Comment: I know that the optional chaining operator is supported in *TypeScript* for some time now. But I thought that it is only recently introduced in JavaScript/EcmaScript (version 2020 if I'm not mistaken). So perhaps the OP cannot use it yet. For example if older browsers or IE need to be supported.

Comment: That's true, check the compatiblity here -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#browser_compatibility

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I would use an intermediate step to store the `find` result.

```js
const found = data.find(t => t.user);
const value = found || found.name;
```

But it also depends on what you expect `value` to become if the item is not found in the `data` array. If you want to fallback to an empty string if it's not found, you could use:

```js
const found = data.find(t => t.user);
const value = found ? found.name : '';
```